# Cox proportional hazard model fit to complex survey data

Tags: survival, experiment-design

What type goodness-of-fit statistics may be used to evaluate the fit of a cox proportional hazard model to complex survey data?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like an AIC value?
I can get this in R using the svycoxph procedure in the survey package
if I make a survey design object

des<-svydesign(ids=~PSU, strata=~STRATA, weights=~weights, data=mydata)

and fit a cox ph model:

fitcox<-svycoxph(Surv(age, event)~x, design=des)

I can calculate an AIC using
2*length(coef(fitcox)) - 2*fitcox$ll[2]

because R stores the fit model log Likelihood in the second slot of fitcox$ll

for the fit model, versus the AIC for the null model
2 -2*fitcox$ll[1]

because R stores the null model log Likelihood in the first slot of fitcox$ll

I'm not sure that SAS dumps out the log likelihood and I don't use stata or spss

Comment: You need no additional packages to get the AIC of a Cox model. Try `extractAIC()`

Comment: If you use a complex survey design, as the OP said, you must use the correct procedure for estimating the standard errors of the estimates, svycoxph does this, and extractAIC on a survey design object does not work

Comment: Oh. I wasn't aware of that. sorry

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to calculate the AIC index when analysing survey data: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/likelihood-ratio-test/

Comment: I emailed the author of the `survey` package about this; he indicated [a different formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/294829/68397) and will be updating the package with an `extractAIC` method for survey-weighted Cox models.

Answer (score 2):

The same arguments as for parametric models in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/jssam/article/3/1/1/915356/AIC-and-BIC-for-modeling-with-complex-survey-data) would suggest using a penalty of

```
2*sum(diag(solve(fitcox$inv.info, fitcox$var)))
```

which reduces to the usual penalty under simple random sampling.